# Why does Java takes Input in String format only?

Tags: java, c

In java when we take input from console we get a String, even if we want an integer as input we get a input in String format, then we covert it in integer format using several methods, like Integer.parseInt(). Where as C/C++ also take input from console but there we get integer values directly from console we does not require methods to convert them. Then why does java follows such long procedure. **What is the reason behind such an architecture of Java ?

```
//In java we follow the following process

public static void main(String args[])
{int i = Integer.parseInt( args[0]);// here we get input in String format and then convert it
}

//In C++ we follow the following :

void main()
{int i;
 cin>>i;
}
Both C/C++ and Java takes input form Console then why java takes it in String Format and C++ does not ??
```

Comment: I'm almost certain you are confusing program arguments with standard input.

Comment: Fyi, there's no thing such as `C/C++`. `C` and `C++` are two different languages.

Comment: I am pretty sure `cin>>i` won't work in `C`

Comment: The short story is that C++ does, it just has the default streams are overloaded to be able to implicitly convert some types. (It's in fact so prominent that a common "convert an abritary value to string" pattern is "feed it such a stream, then get the formatted value".)

Comment: actually my question is no what c use and what c++ use, i just want to know both C++ and java takes input from console than why both of them follow different procedures. Since java is advance than C++ , is the format followed by java is faster than the one followed by C++ ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java -  If you use the [Scanner](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class you can get the input in the required data type. It's not only `String` java accepts.

Comment: but why do java by default do so, is that process faster than process used in C/C++ ?

Comment: Java makes the args variable a String[] because you can put any content in the Console. Sun decided to implement it that way. It has nothing to do with speed.

Comment: @dcpomero...sir but why did sun decided so ? Is there any particular reason behind it, because that is a long process, take input as string and then convert it in other format where as in C++ and C we directly give the input in the demanding format.

Comment: Even in C++ we could give any of the format like integer, float , character. Than why such different procedure in Java.

Answer (score 2):

Check out java.util.Scanner, it might do what you need:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Comment: but why do java by default do so, is that process faster than process used in C/C++ ?

Answer (score 0):

If you take an integer from the console in C, it will require you to atoi() the input.

Comment: You can use scanf, but it no shorter/simpler.

Answer (score 0):

You always get a string when reading from stdin. In C++ however, the `>>` operator overload used when writing to an int performs the conversion - so it's just a different way of converting but in both languages it's necessary.

You are right that it's nicer in C++ though since you can use pretty much the same code no matter what data type you have.